# Is JSON.stringify() supported by IE 8?

Tags: javascript

I need to use:

```
JSON.stringify()
```

which should be supported by Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. I think IE8 also has support for the JSON object. I think IE7 and 6 do not, so I'm doing this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script src="http://www.json.org/json2.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

so, I think this will import the external JavaScript only if IE6 & 7. I looked at the URL where the script is hosted, they are including only if the IE version is less than 9:

```
http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://www.json.org/json2.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

so should I be including this for IE 8 too?

Comment: json.org/json2.js, as it's promised in the source code, is a big fat 404. You may want to use this cdn if you can't host json2.js yourself: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js

Comment: For those in need, the source-file is now located here:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js

Answer (score 66):

To answer the question in the title directly, yes IE8 supports `JSON.stringify()` natively.

IE8 is the first version of IE to get this support, and the functionality is explained in detail by the dev team here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/10/native-json-in-ie8.aspx

The answer the second part of the question, yes you would need to include alternate functionality for IE6/IE7.  Something like Modernizr can make it easy to check this.

Also note if the user is in Compatibility View in IE8, the JSON object will not be available.

Comment: this is the correct answer, but more generally I would recommend looking at [YepNopeJS](http://yepnopejs.com/) or [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to do the check for conditionally loading json library.

Comment: Also note if the user is in Compatibility View, the JSON object will not be available.

Comment: Thanks @nickk_can and Dave, I've updated based on your comments.

Answer (score 32):

If you try `JSON.stringify()` using IE 8 you need to ensure it is not working in compatibility mode. 
See [JSON object undefined in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715373/json-not-defined-internet-explorer-8)

You'll need to add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

to your page

Answer (score 16):

**There's a better solution...**

This doesn't directly answer your question, it provides a complete solution to your problem instead.

The **[jquery-json](https://github.com/krinkle/jquery-json)** library provides a wrapper that uses the native JSON object implementation if it's available and falls back to it's own JSON implementation if it isn't. Meaning it'll work in any browser.

**Here's the Usage Example from the Project's home page:**

```
var thing = {plugin: 'jquery-json', version: 2.3};

var encoded = $.toJSON( thing );
// '{"plugin":"jquery-json","version":2.3}'
var name = $.evalJSON( encoded ).plugin;
// "jquery-json"
var version = $.evalJSON(encoded).version;
// 2.3
```

The usage is very simple: toJSON stringifies the JS source; evalJSON converts JSON string data back to JavaScript objects.

Of you look at the source, the implementation is surprisingly simple but it works very well. I have used it personally in a few projects.

There's no need to do browser detection if it works in every browser.

Comment: I'm not sure what the downvote was for. This is nothing but a JS polyfill for JSON support that falls back to JSON.stringify if the browser supports it.

Comment: i withdraw my comment. i was mentioning that we already have a library.

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize that before adding my answer. TIL, I guess.

Comment: please stop advising jquery plugins

Comment: There is not any `$.toJSON` method.

Answer (score 11):

put following code in your js file ;

```
var JSON = JSON || {};

// implement JSON.stringify serialization
JSON.stringify = JSON.stringify || function (obj) {

var t = typeof (obj);
if (t != "object" || obj === null) {

    // simple data type
    if (t == "string") obj = '"'+obj+'"';
    return String(obj);

}
else {

    // recurse array or object
    var n, v, json = [], arr = (obj && obj.constructor == Array);

    for (n in obj) {
        v = obj[n]; t = typeof(v);

        if (t == "string") v = '"'+v+'"';
        else if (t == "object" && v !== null) v = JSON.stringify(v);

        json.push((arr ? "" : '"' + n + '":') + String(v));
    }

    return (arr ? "[" : "{") + String(json) + (arr ? "]" : "}");
}
};

// implement JSON.parse de-serialization
JSON.parse = JSON.parse || function (str) {
if (str === "") str = '""';
eval("var p=" + str + ";");
return p;
 };
```

Comment: Such a light weight library! I like it

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to use conditionals to determine whether to include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) or not.  Take a look at the source code:

```
var JSON;
if (!JSON) {
    JSON = {};
}

if (typeof JSON.stringify !== 'function') {
    JSON.stringify = function (value, replacer, space) {
        // Code
    }
}

if (typeof JSON.parse !== 'function') {
    JSON.parse = function (text, reviver) {
        // Code
    }
}
```

What this does is first check to see if `JSON` already exists as an object.  If not, then it creates a new object to house the JSON functions.  Then, it checks for a native implementation of `.stringify()` or `.parse()` exist.  If not, then it creates those functions.

Bottom line: if a native implementation exists, including `json2.js` will not overwrite the native implementation.  Otherwise, it'll add that functionality, so there's no reason you need to use conditionals, unless you are trying to minimize requests.

*<sub>(It might also be noted that IE10 does not support conditional statements, so I'd recommend against relying on them unless there isn't any alternative.)</sub>*

Comment: Of course you might not want the extra request in cases where this is not rolled up with some sort of asset packaging.

Comment: If _IE10 does not support conditional statements_ won't it see those lines posted by the OP as just a comment? What am I missing?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Yes, that's true.  But, generally people have been relying on conditional statements to account for variances in Internet Explorer's implementation of standards.  IE10 and above no longer support conditionals, so that comment was related to the OP's use of conditionals.  My answer is that, json2.js, conditionals are not required since it will not overwrite native methods, with the caveat that developers need to start getting away from conditionals for Internet Explorer for future versions.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Would you mind adding a link to json2.js in your answer for those of us who haven't previously encountered it?

Answer (score 3):

A shiv just `createElement`'s the HTML5 elements. It has nothing to do with JSON. Try getting an actual JSON parser like json2.js from Crockford.

Comment: I agree that the json parser is the best bet.

Comment: Ok is the above use correct then - I pointed to the correct js file I think - but is it necessary for IE8? Or does it need to be included only for IE6 and IE7? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow up Mozilla has made a polyfill for the JSON object if you need it to work in IE compatibility mode.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

```
if (!window.JSON) {
  window.JSON = {
    parse: function(sJSON) { return eval('(' + sJSON + ')'); },
    stringify: (function () {
      var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
      var isArray = Array.isArray || function (a) { return toString.call(a) === '[object Array]'; };
      var escMap = {'"': '\\"', '\\': '\\\\', '\b': '\\b', '\f': '\\f', '\n': '\\n', '\r': '\\r', '\t': '\\t'};
      var escFunc = function (m) { return escMap[m] || '\\u' + (m.charCodeAt(0) + 0x10000).toString(16).substr(1); };
      var escRE = /[\\"\u0000-\u001F\u2028\u2029]/g;
      return function stringify(value) {
        if (value == null) {
          return 'null';
        } else if (typeof value === 'number') {
          return isFinite(value) ? value.toString() : 'null';
        } else if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
          return value.toString();
        } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
          if (typeof value.toJSON === 'function') {
            return stringify(value.toJSON());
          } else if (isArray(value)) {
            var res = '[';
            for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
              res += (i ? ', ' : '') + stringify(value[i]);
            return res + ']';
          } else if (toString.call(value) === '[object Object]') {
            var tmp = [];
            for (var k in value) {
            if (value.hasOwnProperty(k))
                tmp.push(stringify(k) + ': ' + stringify(value[k]));
            }
             return '{' + tmp.join(', ') + '}';
          }
        }
        return '"' + value.toString().replace(escRE, escFunc) + '"';
      };
    })()
  };
}
```