# JSON object undefined in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, html, json, internet-explorer-8

Currently I'm writing a JavaScript file and have the following line:

```
var res = "JSON=" + JSON.stringify(result);
```

result is being set just above this line. The issue I'm having is that IE8 (IE8 only, that is) is reporting to me that JSON is undefined somehow. I'm not sure what to make of this since, as I understood it, IE8 is a browser that implemented JSON support. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Are you in compatibility mode?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Make sure you're actually in IE 8 mode by using the preferred method, a standards doctype...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

...or the undesired method, the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag/header...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
```

See [Defining Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=VS.85).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Definitely worth checking this, because compat mode can be triggered without you necessarily realising it - open the Developer Tools (F12) and look in the toolbar for the browser mode.

Comment: I dropped this line in and checked the dev tools. Definitely running in IE8 Standards Mode.

Comment: @keybored: something **must** be overriding the JSON global object then.  Check your code for variations of `JSON =` (the example code you wrote in the question is a good start - are you using `eval`?).

Comment: I haven't seen anything like that but I was wondering something, the above call is being made from within an iframe. Would I need to call up to the parent to actually get at JSON?

Comment: Eventually I did fix the problem. Turns out it wasn't this BUT IE7 compatibility was going to be one of the next things I had to work on and you've no doubt saved me time already. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for correct answer. In my case no problem running locally in VS2010 but when published to IIS 7 64 bit server got the error.

Comment: @keybored what was your solution?

Comment: It's been a while buit IIRC it was either a bug in my JS code or a transient Facebook bug. Wish I could remember specifically.

Comment: Please use the doctype instead of the X-UA-Compatible junk

Comment: @SystemParadox: just for you, I've clarified the answer :p

Comment: @SystemParadox sorry for reviving this but i do have a valid doctype yet i still had problems with IE10 i do not have Comp mode manually set so im not sure what triggered it, my code is html valid so the only thing that worked for me is the X-UA junk, any thoughts ?

Comment: My thoughts? IE is broken. I don't use it. I don't expect to see the DOM cluttered with its junk either. If IE's JS environment is broken, load a JS shim that fixes it. Or just show an error...

Answer (score 9):

Using [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) solved this for me, in case you are already using JQuery.

Answer (score 6):

Other things that absence of doctype or wrong doctype, or some error with html syntax, will force IE to use document modes different from what you expect.

I was using simple "" in a test document and the absence of TITLE tag as a child of HEAD tag made window.JSON become undefined.

Remember always that it's better to test the resource against the version of browser. And, if your users can use IE's with emulation of document modes, it's better you have a piece of code  to provide the JSON.parse and JSON.stringify when natives are undefined.

Answer (score 3):

```
function parseJson(jsonString) {
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 8) {
        return eval('(' + jsonString + ')');
    }
    else {
        return JSON.parse(jsonString);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

May happen despite `<!DOCTYPE html>` if the page encoding is `UTF-8` with `BOM` (byte order mark). Try saving the file as `UTF-8` without `BOM`, using a suitable text editor.

Answer (score 1):

put following code in your js file ;

```
var JSON = JSON || {};

// implement JSON.stringify serialization
JSON.stringify = JSON.stringify || function (obj) {

var t = typeof (obj);
if (t != "object" || obj === null) {

    // simple data type
    if (t == "string") obj = '"'+obj+'"';
    return String(obj);

}
else {

    // recurse array or object
    var n, v, json = [], arr = (obj && obj.constructor == Array);

    for (n in obj) {
        v = obj[n]; t = typeof(v);

        if (t == "string") v = '"'+v+'"';
        else if (t == "object" && v !== null) v = JSON.stringify(v);

        json.push((arr ? "" : '"' + n + '":') + String(v));
    }

    return (arr ? "[" : "{") + String(json) + (arr ? "]" : "}");
}
};

// implement JSON.parse de-serialization
JSON.parse = JSON.parse || function (str) {
if (str === "") str = '""';
eval("var p=" + str + ";");
return p;
 };
```

Comment: Leaving aside the lack of any attempt to actually answer the *question*, this is terrible code. Besides the opaque one-letter variable names, the broken formatting, and the resort to `eval` for parsing, the kicker is that the stringifier doesn't even work; it returns the wrong result for any string containing a double quote, a newline, a backslash, or probably plenty of other things.

Answer (score -1):

Check jQuery version.
[jQuery 2.0 drops support for IE 6, 7 and 8](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/). Use jQuery 1.x instead, which is still officially supported.
you can use this Code.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

read more about [jquery migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme).

if not working check [this article](http://chapter31.com/2012/11/21/json-undefined-issues-on-ie8-and-ie9/).

Comment: The OP has not said that he is using jQuery, and even if he were, he is asking about the native `JSON` global which is not part of jQuery. This answer is utterly and entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the undefined error was because I was missing a JSON library.

You can add JSON object like this (replace the relative path with your own path):

```
<script>
        if (typeof window.JSON == 'undefined') {
          document.write('<script src="../scripts/json2.js"><\/script>'); 
        }
</script>
```

For json2 library:
http://cdnjs.com/libraries/json2/

There is also a json3 library:
http://cdnjs.com/libraries/json3/

Then you can refer to it in your code:

```
var array = [];
array[1] = "apple";
array[2] = "orange";
alert(JSON.stringify(array));
```