# Why would X-UA-Compatible IE-Edge fix JSON undefined error

Tags: jquery, html, json

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

I found the above line of code online somewhere and added it to my index file. Before I did in IE8 I was getting JSON undefined error when I tried to use the  JSON.stringify. When I added it it stoped the JSON undefined error. Can someone please explain why and what the code does. I have found many convoluted answers online but still don't understand it.

```
var object = {
  track:'bla',
  name:'bla bla'
}
JSON.stringify(object);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE8, JSON is only natively supported in Standards Mode. The meta tag you provided (or the appropriate HTTP header) puts IE8 into Standards Mode, rather than Quirks Mode. In Quirks Mode IE8 does not natively support the JSON object.

See also [Defining document compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Please see here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4715399/359940

Could it be possible that you were in compatibility mode?