# IE8 is showing up as IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am creating a form which will very likely be used in IE8.  I am using jQuery.  In my JS script, I do  JSON.stringify on an object and this where IE8 fails.

I did a little search and found this:
[JSON object undefined in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715373/json-object-undefined-in-internet-explorer-8-dom)

I wanted to make sure that I did have IE8 but come to find out I don't.

```
alert(jQuery.browser.msie);
alert(jQuery.browser.version);
alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);

true
7.0
1.7.2
```

Why does it say 7.0 when the "About Internet Explorer" window shows

```
Version: 8.0.7601.17514
```

What's going on?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe the jQuery properties you are using are obsolete now. You should consider looking at modernizr: http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Don't do browser detection, do feature detection. Something like `if(JSON && JSON.stringify)`. or use modernizr as drew suggested. Quite possibly you have IE in "quirks" mode.

Comment: The [jQuery API page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) notes that IE8 claims to be 7 in Compatibility View and suggests using something like Modernizr instead.

Comment: Try this: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE">`

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan Wouldn't `IE=EDGE` suffice?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of IE Compatibility Mode!

Comment: @Tarun It might, I haven't bothered to read the docs throughly on this, and won't.