# IE 8 Doesn't Recognize JSON, Options?

Tags: javascript

I have a page using the JSON object; in the latest Chrome/Firefox, and IE 11 it is utilized fine but in IE 8 it isn't recognized. Specifically it is "undefined"; the following Stack article discusses the same problem: [JSON object undefined in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715373/json-object-undefined-in-internet-explorer-8-dom)

The above article suggests using a specific meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
```

Currently my page uses:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

I have several questions; first is this the only option? If not what alternatives are there? Second is it possible to do something as follows:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE 8]>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<![endif]-->
```

I ask about the above conditional as I am updating a corporate application and I want to insure maximum verisimilitude. Any suggestions are appreciated. BTW, the problem originated using

```
JSON.parse();
```

IE 8 does support JSON:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/10/native-json-in-ie8.aspx

Comment: Those 2 `<meta>` tags have nothing to do with each other, you can have them both on the page at the same time just fine.  In fact, you don't need the conditional comments.  Also, do you have a DOCTYPE?  See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx, you want "Standards mode".  http://caniuse.com/#search=JSON

Comment: As you can see, the `http-equiv` value is different in both cases, so they are simply two `meta` tags containing different information.

Comment: The answer to the original question is about doctypes, not content-types. If the accepted answer there is anything to go by, you are in "compatibility mode" in IE8, and that's what you need to get out of. DOCTYPE is the answer, normally.

Comment: So basically the linked answer says to set a standard HTML5 doctype to make sure you're in IE8 mode, and did you try doing just that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js for cross browser implementation of JSON and all its functions

Comment: Because IE8 *does* have `JSON` natively.  http://caniuse.com/#search=JSON  You just need to make sure it's in "standards mode".  (I didn't downvote, BTW)

Comment: It seems like you haven't read the question at all. I mean, technically including that library is an alternative, but there is a better solution, which is adding the meta tag.

Comment: Thanks Felix, I consider this an "answer"; I tested and this works great.

Answer (score -3):

IE8 doesn't natively support JSON, if I remember correctly. You can use a polyfill like Doug Crockford's https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Edit: or a valid doctype?

[JSON object undefined in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715373/json-object-undefined-in-internet-explorer-8-dom)