# Ajax call to WebMethod with parameters is not working in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

Here is my JavaScript method:

```
function CloseDialog() {           
    var ieAppIdstr = $("[id$=hfIEAppId]").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Notes/Notes.aspx/UpdateNoteStatus",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ ieAppId: ieAppIdstr }),
        success: function (data) {

        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            $('#output').text(msg);
        }
    });
    popUpClosed();
}
```

And my web method:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static void UpdateNoteStatus(string ieAppId)
{
    UserRole usrRole = HttpContext.Current.Session[Settings.Default.USERROLE] as UserRole;
    string loggedInUserRole = (usrRole != null && usrRole.IsIMERole) ? "IME" : "PROVIDER";
}
```

This code is working fine in Chrome, but not working in IE9 and below. I searched Google and Stack Overflow. All the solutions either suggest to add random data to the url or to make cache false. I have tried both solutions. Still the web method is not getting called.

I might be doing something wrong here possibly... I tried without the parameter and the code works fine. Only when I add the parameter the code does not work.

Please suggest some solution. Thank you :)

EDIT: I am not getting any error. And this code is placed in a jQuery pop up window.

Comment: Error in IE console? Maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715373/json-object-undefined-in-internet-explorer-8

Comment: If you could provide the error you're receiving, it will probably help us identify the problem. Also, since you said it's not getting called, I'd do a network trace (since it's an IE9 or below issue, fire up Fiddler to see if it's even making an HTTP request).

Comment: I am not getting any error, web method is not invoked when I add parameters.

Comment: Comment rather than answer, as I'm a bit of a jquery newbie myself... do you need the `JSON.stringify`?  Can't it just be `data: { ieAppId: ieAppIdstr },`?

Answer (score 0):

At quick glance, since you said it's an IE9 and below issue, I think the problem is IE9 didn't have JSON.stringify. You can use https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json.js to add the JSON object to older browsers.

Comment: Then I'd go back to suggesting you use Fiddler to see if any network request is being made. If the $.ajax() method is getting called, we want to see what, if anything, is going over the network.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
data: '{ieAppId: "' + ieAppIdstr  + '" }',
```

Comment: @user1181942 it stops working only when `ieAppIdstr` is supplied? are you sure `ieAppIdstr ` is valid?

Comment: Yes.. I believe it is valid.. It is in numeric form.

Comment: Can you check to make sure? Also can you tell me where UpdateNoteStatus is located? Consider that you can use `/` as the root,  you dont have to use `..`

Comment: UpdateNotesStatus is located in code behind file. I also tried using "/" as the root, but no luck :(