# Internet Explorer recognizing Meteor.js app as an intranet site. Won't load

Tags: internet-explorer, meteor

I can see from File > Properties in Internet Explorer 11 that it's recognizing it as a `local intranet` site. It shouldn't be, I have no clue why it is...

This is causing the website to render in Compatibility Mode and does not load--breaks on `JSON` being undefined.

I was attempting to follow this: [JSON object undefined in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715373/json-object-undefined-in-internet-explorer-8). Have only been able to actually try:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Or

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />`

Both are at the top of the `<head>` but, being Meteor, other stuff injected before it.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I use [kadirahq:flow-router](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router) and [kadirahq:dochead](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-dochead) to manage meta tags like these.

Also with the next version of flow-router you'll be able to move the scripts to the end of the page, for faster page loads. See https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router/tree/ssr#defer-script-loading, maybe that could help.