# ASP MVC 3 submit url parameters using AJAX and JQUERY

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I've got a problem using ASP.NET MVC3, AJAX and JQUERY. I've got the following function

```
[HttpPost]
public bool Update(int id, FormCollection collection)
```

This is my jQuery Source:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnUpdate').click(function (e) {
        // Cancel default action
        e.preventDefault();
        var formCollection = $('#formId').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")',
            data: { id: $('#id').val(), collection: formCollection },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('Error during process: \n' + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The id parameter submitted successfully, but the collection (FormCollection) includes an array with {[0]: 10000, [1]: collection}. I can't fix the problem. When I redesign the solution like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool Update(FormCollection collection)

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnUpdate').click(function (e) {
        // Cancel default action
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
            data: $('#formId').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('Error during process: \n' + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

everything works fine. What I'm doing wrong in passing 2 parameter?

THX!!!

Comment: this way not get `FormCollection` you have pass collection of model class define here. like `public bool Update(int id, userProfile collection)`

Comment: make sure in IE check this [Is JSON.stringify() supported by IE 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326893/is-json-stringify-supported-by-ie-8)

Answer (score 1):

Try calling JSON.stringify() on your JSON:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ id: $('#id').val(), collection: formCollection })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnUpdate').click(function (e) {
        // Cancel default action
        e.preventDefault();
        var formCollection = $('#formId').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: $('#id').val(), collection: formCollection }),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('Error during process: \n' + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

you should have to pass the data with jsonstringify

Comment: Creates the following error: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'...

Comment: it means you also have to look on your id field

Comment: or make [HttpPost]
public bool Update(int id, FormCollection collection) to [HttpPost]
public bool Update(int? id, FormCollection collection)

Comment: id should not be an optional parameter! jquery and ajax have to submit the unique id and the form collection...

Comment: have you checked what you are getting in id through alert

Comment: or check by debugger are you getting rht value of id the above code is not responsible what you facing this time paste your htnl too

Comment: The id parameter got the correct value id=10000 but the FormCollection parameter got an array {[0] "id", [1] "collection"}

Comment: what you are getting on action as a parameter can you able to disclose it

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual watch:
[image: Debugging]

Parameter ID submitted successfully (Name=id, Wert=10000). Above id you can see formCollection including FORM.serialize() values of the ajax call. But the System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection including two keys only: **id** and **collection**! I expected

1. "Name"
2. "Address"
3. "Address_2"
4. ...

I think if got a mistake in creating my ajax request, but I don't know why...

```
var customerNo = $('#fieldID').val();
var formCollection = $('#formID').serialize();
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
    data: { id: customerNo, collection: formCollection },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            alert(data);
        };
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('Error during process: \n' + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

The following line generates an error:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ id: customerNo, collection: formCollection })
```

*The parameters dictionary contains a null entry 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'...*

Changed without effect:

```
data: { id: customerNo, collection: JSON.stringify(formCollection) },
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea (works!)

Add in a partial class from a model an string attribute, add this attribute manually in "data".

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
        data: $("form").serialize() + "&id=whatever",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                        alert(data);
                };
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('Error during process: \n' + xhr.responseText);
        }
});
```

**partialClass.cs Model:**

```
public partial class TableName
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public bool Update(FormCollection collection){
    var ID = collection.id; 
}
```

Regards!