# Knockout UNable to Bind $root

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Inside my Document i've added
`<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div>` to my html5 page. Unfortunately IE8 gives me an Error 'Unable to apply binding to $root' or similar.

No Problems on FF and Chrome.

How can i retuen a json dump of my current viewmodel for debugging needs?

Comment: Which KO version are you using? What is the exact error message? Can you put together a repro in JSFiddle? Because your posted code work fine in IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/Vp2Zx/

Comment: Message is as following:
Unable to parse bindings.
Message: [object Error];
Bindings value: text: ko.toJSON($root)

Comment: I was able to repro it. And the problem is the ko.toJSON which uses `JSON.stringify` internally which is in therory is supported in IE8 but it is not working for some reason. Reference the JSON2.js (e.g form here http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js) and it should work in IE8. See also this github issue: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/574

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to repro your issue: the problem isn't with your binding but with the `ko.toJSON` call. Knockout uses the `JSON.stringify` function internally which fails in your case.

Altough [Is JSON.stringify() supported by IE 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326893/is-json-stringify-supported-by-ie-8?lq=1)
where the answer is **yes**.

But sometimes it is just not working: [JSON object undefined in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715373/json-not-defined-internet-explorer-8) because IE is too picky and if you have errors in your html markup it will fall back to compatibility mode where there is no `JSON.stringify` definied.

You have two options:

- Check your HTML to make IE8 happy and don't render it in compatibility mode
- Use [JSON2](http://www.json.org/js.html) library which provides `JSON.stringify` in older browsers.