# a can not load page while use Jquery Mobile 1.3.0 and knockoutjs

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I had write a html code use jquery mobile 1.2.0 and knockoutjs as below

```
<div id="shoppingCar" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="headernav">
        <a data-transition="slide" data-bind="html:editTextForLeft, click:$root.editFuncForLeft, attr:{href: $root.getHref }">add</a>
        <h2>order</h2>
        <a data-bind="click:toEditModel, html:editText" data-mini="true">edit</a>
    </div>
```

it work well(no errors no warns and the add attribute can load page #goodsAdd),but when I update jquery mobile 1.2.0 to 1.3.0,the attribute a can not load goodsAdd page. anyone can help me ? thanks a lot

Comment: can you provide a jsFiddle. Is the problem only in IE? Perhaps this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382467/knockout-unable-to-bind-root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, and found the answer on the knockout.js site.  Just add "return true" to the end of the click handlers.

> Note 3: Allowing the default click action
>
> By default, Knockout will prevent the click event from taking any
>   default action. This means that if you use the click binding on an a
>   tag (a link), for example, the browser will only call your handler
>   function and will not navigate to the link’s href. This is a useful
>   default because when you use the click binding, it’s normally because
>   you’re using the link as part of a UI that manipulates your view
>   model, not as a regular hyperlink to another web page.
>
> However, if you do want to let the default click action proceed, just
>   return true from your click handler function.