# how force set selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm try set selected with javascript and jquery but dont set the value, my code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="destino" name="destino" required>
</select>
```

this is my select for append the options i use a cycle for:

```
for(i=0; i<subdirectorios.length; i++){
 temporal_value =path_directorioPrincipal.concat(subdirectorios[i]);
 var option = $("<option value="+temporal_value+">"+ subdirectorios[i] +"</option>");

  //append option
  $("#modalProceso #destino").append(option);

}
```

**the output:**
[image: output]
**i don't understand why set value as** :

```
value="media/gestionDocumental/Operativos/Prueba" produccion=""
```

in the console return this value:

```
media/gestionDocumental/Operativos/Troquelado
media/gestionDocumental/Operativos/Prueba Produccion
```

for set selected use:

```
$('#destino option:contains("' + destino_path + '")').attr("selected", true)
//or this:
$('#destino').val(destino_path);
```

but dont set selected.
please any suggest..thanks..!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128440/how-to-preserve-space-in-html-select-option-listoption-value-hi-thishi-opti I think this might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly - You need to wrap your options value in quotes otherwise when space occurs it'll be parsed as a separate property.

```
$("<option value='"+ temporal_value +"'>"+ subdirectorios[i] +"</option>");
```

As for your second issue you actually should call `.change()` after setting the option value, like below:

```
$("#destino").val(destino_path).change();
```

[Sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0a2moyz/)

Comment: thanks you solve my problem on set values for options only the problems is set seleted..by consele insert this: $("#destino").val('media/gestionDocumental/Estrategicos/calidad');

Comment: and set selected but by my javascript file dont set selected