# how to concatenate all the word of a sentence in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of sentence which i am passing in the select option and in the option i want to pass a merged words sentence as a value but i am unable to do it how can i merge all the words in a sentence

```
const textArray = ["hello world","hello india","hello usa"];
textArray.forEach((doc) => {
          selectIssueId.innerHTML += `<option value=${doc} id=${doc}>${doc}</option>`;
        });
```

i wanted to pass in the value and the expected output is

```
helloworld ,helloindia,hellousa
```

and if possible i wanted to convert this joined words in their previous way also like this

```
helloworld => hello world
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you want to do.

Comment: Your question and expected behavior is not very clear to me. But you may find the [Array join()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) method to be helpful.

Comment: @srk i know this method but this doesn't work in my case

Comment: @rambtumber What are you trying to do? Please elaborate.

Comment: @iota basically i want to convert a sentence like this  'hello world' into 'helloworld'

Comment: So all you want to do is remove the whitespace from a sentence? If so, regexp would be helpful to you. @Sarabadu's answer: ```.replace(/\s/g, '')```

Comment: @kmp yes and wanted to make it normal after that

Comment: Well, I would store the original sentence somewhere in my code or in a json or txt or whatever, cuz it makes it easier to manipulate back and forth. You could always use the original sentence

Comment: no basically i have to extract the value from the select and i cannot take value or show in this type in the frontend so i have to convert it back in hello world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want this output:

```html
<option value="helloworld" id="helloworld">hello world</option>
<option value="helloindia" id="helloindia">hello india</option>
<option value="hellousa" id="hellousa">hello usa</option>
```

You can remove spaces with this regex replace `str.replace(/\s/g, '')`

```js
textArray.forEach((doc) => {
          let modifiedDoc = doc.replace(/\s/g, '') 
          selectIssueId.innerHTML += 
`<option value="${modifiedDoc}" id="${modifiedDoc}">
      ${doc}
 </option>`; 
        });
```

**Note** that we use `modifiedDoc` for the value and id and `doc` for the display value

Comment: first i have to convert hello world into helloworld that i don't know

Comment: whit this `modifiedDoc = doc.replace(/\s/g, '') ` you are converting "hello world" into "helloworld". if you need to convert it before the for each, please elaborate why to see betters solutions

Comment: can you suggest how can i convert it into the previous version

Comment: because i am trying to store the option value into the backend and i can't store in this helloworld format

Comment: so, you can use `value=${doc}`  and you will save it in "hello world" format

Comment: no in that case i only recieved hello that's why i need to merge them and later i have to reverse that to original

Comment: i missed the `"` there you need to put it like `value="${doc}"`, 
without  the " you get  `<option value=hello world id=helloworld>hello world</option>` but is fixed with enclosing " `<option value="hello world" id="helloworld">hello world</option>`

please give it a try

Comment: here you have a nice reference (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128440/how-to-preserve-space-in-html-select-option-listoption-value-hi-thishi-opti)

Answer (score 0):

```
const textArray = ["hello world","hello india","hello usa"];
textArray.forEach((doc) => {
          selectIssueId.innerHTML += `<option value='${doc}' id=${doc}>${doc}</option>`;
        });
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.