# JSON is Undefined in IE8 Mode (IE11 Browser)

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do#) excellent SO question on the different modes the META http-equiv supported. However, a situation we're looking at confused me with this post which seems to be different from whats been upvoted as standard behaviour in the responses.

We have the following configured in our website:

In the live  environment things are working fine. However, in our QA environments we get the **JSON is undefined** error. I checked the Now if according to that post if using above tag OVERRIDES the default IE compatibility view settings (ie Display Intranet sites in compatibility view) - shouldnt this tags presence fix the situation? however, in our QA environments we continue to see the **JSON is undefined**

Comment: Have you added the `X-UA-Compatible` `<meta>` tag to your `<head>`? If so, can you please provide a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see the problem?

Comment: yes - the code is pretty much standard. Its added to the HEAD tag and its been that way a while. Its only recently we added the JSON.parse notion to a javascript function on the page where we started noticing this.

Comment: The real question is probably why on earth you're worrying about a browser that noone supports anymore ?

Comment: @adeneo there are 422 reasons I could give you :) and they are all the reason why I posted this question. Each one of them have that browser. Mine's not to reason why - only to help them surmount the problem. Can we get back on the topic please?

Comment: Compatibility mode is a kind of **quirk** mode. Try to configure your test environment to something real (except your production environment must use deprecated IE7)

Comment: Use conditional comments to include json2.js for any IE version less than 9. Like shown in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326893/is-json-stringify-supported-by-ie-8. It's not worth it to micro-optimize or obsess about Compatibility Mode. Just include the JSON library and move on.